Split-tunnel VPN with openconnect-sso
I was happily using the OpenConnect plugin for NetworkManager on Linux (Kubuntu), restricting the VPN use to a particular subnet. I did that in the GUI, by specifying an IPv4 route (x.y.z.w, mask 255.255.0.0) and checking the boxes "Ignore automatically obtained routes" and "Use only for the resources in this connection" (might not be the exact words).
Now they have changed the VPN at work to require SSO and 2FA and the plugin doesn't work. I've installed openconnect-sso, and it works fine, but it routes all traffic through the VPN, and I'd like to route only the subnet traffic. I've tried passing --script='vpn-slice x.y.z.w/16' to the openconnect-sso command, but it seems to be ignored, at least I don't see the corresponding line when running route -n.
What would be the command line equivalent to my settings? Should I expect it to work with openconnect-sso?
ETA: My mistake(s). First, vpn-slice is something I have to install too (and make it available for root). Then, I should add openconnect_args before --script. Then it works.
